# How does macOS "detect malware downloaded with Safari"?

Tags: safari, security, malware, high-sierra, sip

On Apple's website, the company makes this claim about macOS High Sierra's security features:

[image: macOS' malware detection]

Can anyone give me more details on the technology that enables macOS to determine if a file downloaded with Safari is a malware ? I'm just curious to see how it compares with an antivirus (no need to start a discussion about why you need or don't need an antivirus on Mac or in general, please not for the 10000th time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the [XProtect](https://www.howtogeek.com/217043/xprotect-explained-how-your-macs-built-in-anti-malware-works/) / file quarantine scheme built into the OS.  macOS has a hard-coded list of file signatures in `/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.bundle/Contents/Resources/XProtect.plist`.  If a file matches one of the signatures, it gets flagged and quarantined.  The list is silently updated, outside the usual software-update mechanism.

It is effectively a very rudimentary blacklist of known malware.  XProtect does not provide active scanning or heuristic-based protection offered by typical antivirus products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So if a file is downloaded on the computer through a drive-by attack via a script on a website for example, XProtect won't catch it as it only scans files downloaded voluntarily by the user ?

Comment: AFAIK it tracks this by source application.  If the executable code came through a quarantine-able app (for example, a browser like Safari), whether through user action or drive-by automatic download, the resulting download is flagged.  You'll typically see a warning dialog "<AppName> is an application downloaded from the Internet" if it doesn't match an XProtect entry, and something like  "we blocked this from running" dialog if it did match.